# how to remove a AFK from the nickname without say the prefix

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so I make a simple AFK command
like this

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.includes('!afk')) {
      message.member.setNickname(`[AFK] ${message.member.displayName} `).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  
  if (message.content === '!back') {
    message.member.setNickname(message.member.displayName.replace('[AFK] ', )).catch(error => console.log(error));

  }

 
  
  
});
```

and I want If the user is afk and then user chat like "hi" the [AFK] is gone without say the prefix "!back"

How can I do that?

Thank You for helping me (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know how Discord works and when exactly the "message" event is triggered, but it seems to me that you could probably do it even without the `set`, as proposed by @TheCave3:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  const pref='[AFK] ';
  if (message.content.includes('!afk'))
    message.member.setNickname(pref+message.member.displayName).catch(error => console.log(error));
  else if (message.member.displayName.slice(0,pref.length)===pref)
    message.member.setNickname(message.member.displayName.slice(pref.length)).catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are asking to delete the AFK status when the player types something again.
I made a rough solution using JS [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set?retiredLocale=it) that should work well with a small set of users, but it may require additional tweaks for large servers.

Basically, when a player types `!afk` it is included in the set of AFK players and when he/she/it comes back and types something, its name is deleted from the set and its nickname updated.
<s>I am not sure if the `message.member.id` exists and it is the correct field to track the player</s> (**EDIT**: [Yes, it is](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=id)), but the main idea is to keep record of something unique for each afk player.

```
    const afkPlayers = new Set();
    
    client.on('message', message => {
      if (message.content.includes('!afk')) {
          afkPlayers.add(message.member.id);
          message.member.setNickname(`[AFK] ${message.member.displayName} `).catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
      
      if(afkPlayers.member.has(message.member.id)){
        afkPlayers.member.delete(message.member.id);
        message.member.setNickname(message.member.displayName.replace('[AFK] ', )).catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
      
});
```